# org.xml.sax.SAXException: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'

Tags: java, apache-camel

Please, I'm trying to use Apache Camel to load routes during runtime. Version 4.0.4, JDK17 and no spring-boot usage.

```java
var routesLoader = camelContext.getCamelContextExtension().getContextPlugin(RoutesLoader.class);
Resource resource = ResourceHelper.fromBytes(path, xml.getBytes());
routesLoader.loadRoutes(resource);
```

This is the content I'm using as XML for test purpose:

```java
private static String camelValidStr = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
    + " <beans "
       +" xmlns='http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"
       +" xsi:schemaLocation='"
          +" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd" 
          +" http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd'"
          +" >"
       +" <camelContext id='camel' xmlns='http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring'>" +
       " </camelContext>"
   +" </beans>";
```

But I got an error like this:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Line: 1, Column: 478, error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.
```

Any suggestions? recommendations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is old legacy Spring `<beans>` XML files that you need Spring to load.
Camel XML DSL is pure Camel, where you can have `<route>` or `<routes>` etc.